# Eclipse application - adding a python console plugin

Tags: eclipse, pydev, rcp

I'm developing an eclipse application in Linux and I'm fairly new to eclipse RCP.
My application is built from already existing plugins, such as eclipse's project explorer, etc.

I'd like to add the pydev python console as a plugin to my application.
I know that adding plugins to an eclipse application is done through the extensions tab on MANIFEST.MF but I can't find any examples on google on adding the pydev console.

Can someone help?
Thanks,
Dolev.

Comment: I suggest you take a look on PyDev open source code.

Comment: http://pydev.org/developers.html has instructions on grabbing PyDev... you should be able to use it in your project.